# Postgres PostGIS left join query performance

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-performance

The db structure is more or less like this and cant be modified. I can only add some indexes but cant set for example foreign keys:

```
    CREATE TABLE adresspoint
(
  id character varying(3999) NOT NULL,
  "position" geometry(PointZ,25832)
  CONSTRAINT pk_adresspoint PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE INDEX adresspoint_idx_position
  ON adresspoint
  USING gist
  ("position");

CREATE TABLE house
(
  id character varying(3999) NOT NULL,
  adresspointid character varying(3999),
  CONSTRAINT pk_house PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE INDEX house_idx_adresspointid
  ON house
  USING btree
  (adresspointid COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

I have query like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT house.id 
FROM house 
   LEFT JOIN adresspoint ON adresspoint.id = house.adresspointid 
             AND st_contains(st_makeenvelope('562827','6326412','563365','6326590',25832),adresspoint.position)
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10
```

and it runs very quickly (100 ms) but when I change it to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT house.id 
FROM house 
  LEFT JOIN adresspoint ON adresspoint.id = house.adresspointid 
        AND st_contains(st_makeenvelope('562827','6326412','563365','6326590',25832),adresspoint.position)
WHERE adresspoint.id is not null -- ***change is here***
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10
```

It runs very slowly (like 100 times slower).

I wonder what is the reason behind it and is there any way I can optimize it? I have indexes on position, ids etc.

Here are execution plans:

faster:

```
Limit  (cost=657.35..9907.84 rows=10 width=86) (actual time=6.864..7.036 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=657.35..632794743.21 rows=6682119 width=86) (actual time=6.852..6.978 rows=10 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ((adresspoint.id)::text = (house.adresspointid)::text)
               ->  Index Scan using pk_house on pk_house house (cost=0.56..17531908.09 rows=6841197 width=123) (actual time=0.077..0.159 rows=10 loops=1)
               ->  Materialize  (cost=656.80..68209.88 rows=5995 width=37) (actual time=0.678..0.678 rows=0 loops=10)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on adresspoint  (cost=656.80..68179.90 rows=5995 width=37) (actual time=6.757..6.757 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ('0103000020E86'::geometry ~ "position")
                           Filter: _st_contains('010300002'::geometry, "position")
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on adresspoint_idx_position  (cost=0.00..655.30 rows=17984 width=0) (actual time=6.737..6.737 rows=0 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ('0103000020E86'::geometry ~ "position")
 Planning time: 22.333 ms
 Execution time: 7.634 ms
```

slower:

```
 Limit  (cost=657.35..40441.29 rows=10 width=86) (actual time=24242.233..24242.233 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=657.35..632794743.21 rows=159058 width=86) (actual time=24242.225..24242.225 rows=0 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ((house.adresspointid)::text = (adresspoint.id)::text)
               ->  Index Scan using pk_house on pk_house house  (cost=0.56..17531908.09 rows=6841197 width=123) (actual time=0.074..12008.484 rows=8222065 loops=1)
               ->  Materialize  (cost=656.80..68209.88 rows=5995 width=37) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=0 loops=8222065)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on adresspoint (cost=656.80..68179.90 rows=5995 width=37) (actual time=5.294..5.294 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ('0103000020E8640000010'::geometry ~ "position")
                           Filter: ((id_lokalid IS NOT NULL) AND _st_contains('0103000020E864'::geometry, "position"))
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on adresspoint_idx_position  (cost=0.00..655.30 rows=17984 width=0) (actual time=5.286..5.286 rows=0 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ('0103000020E'::geometry ~ "position")
 Planning time: 17.286 ms
 Execution time: 24242.705 ms
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Ok done, can you check now? @a_horse_with_no_name